# Liferay-JBoss bundle - css url relative path

Tags: css, url, tomcat, jboss, liferay

---

On the **server machine** (running on Linux) I use Liferay bundled with JBoss.

I started to develop my custom theme based on the default (classic) liferay theme.

There is the file `main.css` where on the last line there is `@import url(custom.css);` (the files *main.css* and *custom.css* are in the same directory).

But Liferay could not find the file `custom.css` so my custom theme style could not be loaded. Then I changed that last line to `@import url(./custom.css);` (I added `./` to the beginning of the url path to explicitly tell css, "hey, search for the file in the current directory") and it worked, so the `custom.css` file then loaded properly.

---

On my **local machine** (running on Windows) I use Liferay bundled with Tomcat.

I tried the same thing there, but there was not any problem with the relative paths at all, so this code `@import url(custom.css);` (without explicitly writing `./` to the beginning of the url path) worked well.

---

The **differences** between the server and the local machine are:

- Developer machine - Linux, JBoss
- Local machine - Windows, Tomcat

and on both machines there is the same version of Liferay (6.1.30 EE GA3).

---

I do not know which causes this problem. Maybe I should change some JBoss settings, or some Linux settings, or some Java settings, or something else to get it working on the developer machine.

**In short**, on the developer machine, `@import url(custom.css);` does not work, but `@import url(./custom.css);` works well. Why?